# Is Misheyakir affected by clouds?

Tags: zemanim, shacharis-morning-prayer, weather

Does the time of Misheyakir in the morning get affected if it's overcast. Because then technically it's not Misheyakir.

Comment: It seems to be only an astronomical calculations (which would lead me to believe that a blind person can daven after it even though he still can't see the difference).

Answer (score 4):

According to at least one [opinion](http://havolim.blogspot.com/2008/10/hello-im-back.html), yes it is though I don't know exactly how seriously to take this source.

> What is the earliest time you can make a bracha on your talis/tzitzis? Of course, the zman is Misheyakir, as in OC 18, when you can discern between undyed wool and tcheiles, or when you can recognize a casual acquaintance from a few feet away. When is that? The shittos vary from 66 minutes before sunrise (Pri Megadim, but very few hold like this le'halacha) to 60 minutes before sunrise (see Taharas Yom Tov, VII, 92) to 35 minutes before sunrise (Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, LeTorah ve-Hora'ah, no. 3, p. 7). Of course, you should consult YLOR. **But if you follow Reb Moshe, your should know that Reb Moshe’s shittah is that just like a blind person is pattur from tzitzis, Misheyakir depends on the actual, local, subjective misheyakir, and if it’s cloudy, then it’s later.**

(I added the bold).

Comment: ...which means that according to R' Moshe, on very unusual days (solar eclipse or ch"v a volcano) it might be impossible to daven vasikin.  Or in the volcano case, misheyakir might not even happen before sof zman krias shema and you'd be totally patur.

Answer (score -2):

The time of "Misheyakir" in the morning is NOT affected if the sky is overcast, much the same as "Shekiya", halachic sunset, is not affected on a cloudy day.

These are "technical" times, which relate to where the sun is currently located, in relation to the horizon.

Comment: A source would greatly improve this answer...

Comment: See OC (293:2) regarding Motzei Shabbos on a cloudy day. ואם הוא יום מעונן, ימתין עד שיצא הספק מלבו, which indicates that we do not require the actual physical phenomena, rather it is a reference to an astronomical reality. See also Mishna Berura (ad loc. 7) that on a cloudy day, a person can rely on an accurate clock.

Comment: a. All relevant information should be [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/95845/edit)ed in to the body of your answer, rather than left as a comment. b. How do you know that the rules for motzei shabbat and misheyakir are the same?